# Map service roles and replicas to servers with Azure DevOps Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My project is Windows Service application which could be installed in several roles (the difference is in service name, exe path and some setting in app.config). Each role could be scaled horizontally by instances count. And all these {roles x replica counts} should be deployed over a set of servers in specific proportions for effective performance and utilization.

As an example:

ServerA

- ServiceAlfa.1
- ServiceAlfa.2
- ServiceBravo
- ServiceDelta

ServerB

- ServiceBravo
- ServiceCharlie
- ServiceDelta.1
- ServiceDelta.2
- ServiceDelta.3

How can I achieve this with Azure DevOps (Dev17.M153.5) instruments?
I know brand new yaml pipeline introduces some conception of Environments and VM. It's just not available in latest stable version yet. But it's like a replacement for Deployment Groups early used for deployment to multiple machines, which I can use. I have already installed deployment agents and registered it. But I still cannot figure it out how better configure my complex mapping of instances to servers in release pipeline.

I can create a one job stage per role and link them with corresponding variable groups like

StageAlfa

- ServerA:2

StageBravo

- ServerA:1
- ServerB:1

StageCharlie

- ServerB:1

StageDelta

- ServerA:1
- ServerB:3

So I should check and compare the server name in my script

Or I can do the opposite: create a stage per machine and link it with variable group describing count of specific role replicas on current server. So in every stage I could select specific machine from deployment group by tag.

Looks like the second approach is simpler but they both are felt so awkward!

P.S. Windows Services on Machines not a containers in Kubernetes due to specific Windows software dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your approaches are correct. You may consider migrating to Azure DevOps Service or upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2020, which supports Envorinments and VM:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops#continuous-deployment-in-yaml